# In pandas, how can a DataFrame be filtered by conditions specified for the values of multiple specified columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a simple dataset of a form like the following:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
         [
             ["Norway"     , 7.537,  0.039, 11  , 31],
             ["Denmark"    , 7.522, -0.004,  9  , 12],
             ["Switzerland", 7.494,  None , 15  , 50],
             ["Finland"    , 7.469,  None , None, 29],
             ["Netherlands", 7.377,  1    , None, 77],
         ],
         columns = [
             "country",
             "score A",
             "score B",
             "score C",
             "score D"
         ]
    )
```

How can I filter this dataset such that certain conditions are placed on the values of multiple rows? So, let's say I want to filter the data such that all rows (all countries) that have null values for `score B` *and* `score C` are excluded? This would result in the `Finland` row being excluded.

When I try the following, I get all rows with any null values in either of those columns excluded, resulting in only the `Norway` and `Denmark` rows being included:

```
df[(df["score B"].notnull()) & (df["score C"].notnull())]
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need

```
df[~(df['score B'].isnull() & df['score C'].isnull())]

    country     score A score B score C score D
0   Norway      7.537   0.039   11.0    31
1   Denmark     7.522   -0.004  9.0     12
2   Switzerland 7.494   NaN     15.0    50
4   Netherlands 7.377   1.000   NaN     77
```

Answer (score 1):

How about specifying `or`:

```
df[(df["score B"].notnull()) | (df["score C"].notnull())]
```

Output:

```
       country  score A  score B  score C  score D
0       Norway    7.537    0.039     11.0       31
1      Denmark    7.522   -0.004      9.0       12
2  Switzerland    7.494      NaN     15.0       50
4  Netherlands    7.377    1.000      NaN       77
```

Right? All you want is to exclude cases where **both** are null (or am I not understanding this correctly)?